# How can I generate a new panel based on where my JTable is double-clicked?

Tags: java, swing, action, jpanel, double-click

I need help implementing the following behavior: when a user double-clicks on a row in the `JTable` on `JPanel` A — code snippet for this shown below — the program should redirect the user to `JPanel` B. B should contain some data about whatever was on the `JTable`'s row.

```
private void TableMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
if(evt.getClickCount() == 2){
   System.out.println("Double click");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean, "redirect the user to?"

If the other panel is already visible, you can switch the focus there (though that's a bit unusual behavior which may negatively surprise your user) using `setFocus()` on the second panel.

If the other panel is not visible but has its own space in the GUI, then I guess you'd simply make it visible. If it has to overlay the panel the user just clicked on, then you want to use a `CardLayout` to display two panels alternatively in the same space.

Comment: i mean that double click on a row (in a jTable located in one tab of a JTabbedPane) would automatically focus on whatever it is in a different tab of the same JTabbedPane :)

Comment: Ah, OK. Then you need to implement 2 things in your double click handler: (1) Flip the JTabbedPane to the one you want, and (2) setFocus() on the element you want. If that's another JTable, you'll want to setFocus() on the JTable and additionally setSelection in the JTable's SelectionModel.

Comment: Sure! You can use either `JTabbedPane.setSelectedComponent()` or `setSelectedIndex()`.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this thread: http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=366670
This is essentially the same thing you are trying to do, you just want to respond to mouse double-clicks instead of mouse move events.